# How do I prevent the decimal point from repeating?

Tags: javascript

I am in the early process of creating a calculator and just testing out my code. How do I prevent the decimal point from repeating? Basically, I need the decimal point to only be displayed once when clicked.

```js
let display = document.querySelector('.display');

let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function(numberButtons) {
  numberButtons.addEventListener('click', showNumber)

  function showNumber() {
    if (display.textContent == 0) {
      display.innerHTML = "";
    }
    display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="display">0</div>
    <button class='number' id='one'>1</button>
    <button class='number' id="two">2</button>
    <button class='number' id='decimal-point'>.</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check `display.innerHTML` ... if it has a `.` don't add a `.`

Comment: `if(!(numberButtons.innerHTML.includes('.') && display.innerHTML.includes('.')))` the line before `display.innerHTML += numberButtons.innerHTML;` will do it

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to disable button after it has been pressed. Make sure if you clear values to reset back to (disable: false).

function singleClick() {
document.getElementById("decimal-point").disabled = true;